# The closed points of a scheme and irreducibility

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is a scheme. We say a point $x$ is closed in $X$ if $\overline{\{x\}}=\{x\}$. Let $t(X)$ be the subspace of all closed points in $X$. We say X is irreducible if its topological space is irreducible.

My question is if it is true that $X$ is irreducible if and only if $t(X)$ is irreducible.

And in general if $X$ is only a topological space, $t(X)$ is subspace of all closed points in $X$, if it is true that $ X$ is irreducible if and only if $t(X)$ is irreducible

I try to prove it is right. But I spend a lot of time and do not know how to prove it.

Comment: If a space X has more than two closed points, then $\tau(X)$ will not be irreducible.

Comment: @user45878 I think what you in not correct. For example ,all points in an irreducible variety are closed.

Comment: What about the generic point?

Comment: @user45878 $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]$ has infinitely many closed points, it is irreducible, and the set of its closed points is irreducible.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that. This might actually be true (with some hypothesis on the scheme $X$, for example it has to have a closed point).

Answer (score 7):

This is not true!

1. $t(X)$ irreducible does not imply $X$ irreducible: Let $ X = \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)_{(x,y)}$ (taking the stalk of the union of two lines at the origin). Your points here are prime ideals of $k[x,y]$ containing $(xy)$ contained in $(x,y)$. The only such prime ideals are $(x,y), (x)$ and $(y)$. You have a unique maximal ideal $(x,y)$, so $t(X)$ is irreducible. But $X$ is reducible as $\operatorname{Spec} X = V(x) \cup V(y)$.
2. $X$ is irreducible does not imply $t(X)$ is irreducible: Just take $X$ to be the spectrum of any integral domain with exactly two maximal ideals.

The claim is true if $t(X)$ is dense in $X$, which is the case for example when $X$ is locally of finite type over $k$.

Comment: **Example for (2):** let $S$ the multiplicatively closed subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $T=\mathbb{P}\setminus\{2,3\}$, that is $S=\{kp\in\mathbb{Z}\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\},p\in T,gcd(k,2)=1,gcd(k,3)=1\}$; let $R=\mathbb{Z}_S$ and let $X=\operatorname{Spec}R$. $X$ is an irreducible, affine scheme, with exactly two closed points and a fat point.